# Does CASE with a subquery execute the subquery on not matching conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I would like to implement logic that takes data for a particular column from a joined table, but if it fails, falls back to a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    m.a, m.b,
    CASE 
        WHEN o.c IS NOT NULL 
            THEN o.c
            ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 c FROM other_table 
                  WHERE <predicate over o.* and m.*> 
                  ORDER BY ...)
    END as c
FROM 
    main_table m
LEFT JOIN 
    other_table o ON m.key = o.key
```

Functionally it works perfectly but I am wondering if I really gain any performance benefit from my `CASE` operator. The idea is that matching by key should work in almost all cases, but for some small fraction of rows we need to fall back to a more expensive `TOP 1` search over `other_table`. Is the optimizer smart enough to catch this logic or it evaluates the subquery for every output row regardless?

I am trying to learn from the plan, but I am not quite sure how to interpret that to be honest.

[image]

The top branch is `LEFT JOIN`, which is super fast.

The bottom branch is the `TOP 1` subquery (which is essentially a variant of `LEFT JOIN`).

The highlighted node is the `CASE` operator.

I tried to understand the logic based on the number of rows I get in the "slow" branch:

[image]

But those numbers do not make sense to me. The total number of rows returned by the query (= number of rows in the `main_table`) is 3127. The number of **not joined** rows by `LEFT JOIN` is 328. The plan shows two leafs of constant scan starting with 289 rows. I would understand seeing 328 rows alone, but I don't understand what is 289. Why are there two, which concatenate into 578 and then merge back into 289?

Please help me understand the plan. Is there such a thing as "going into nested loop conditionally"? It looks like the last nested loop calls the bottom branch regardless... Do I need to rewrite the query?

Comment: The plan will probably not do what you're describing, unless you recompile your statement every time. If it's in a procedure, it's going to pick a plan that matches the first set of parameters it sees. And if that hits one plan, a different set of inputs may behave differently.

Comment: I highly doubt if SQL server will evaluate the sub query conditionally. It is a part of from clause, logically speaking.

Comment: The closet thing to what you want is the [adaptive join](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2017-adaptive-join-internals/). It's hard to query your way into that, and it wouldn't happen with a `CASE` expression and a subquery like that, as far as I know.

Comment: With the risk of adding to the confusion rather than being of help: I'm pretty sure I've seen MSSQL being 'smart' about this when using `ISNULL()` (or `COALESCE()`?) rather than a `CASE` structure but it was a slightly less complicated query. Still, worth giving a try to see if that changes the plan and might shed some light on the issue. You should also easily be able to figure out the number of expected calls of the `TOP 1` subquery and see if that numbers matches up somehow with the actual query plan.

Comment: Thanks @deroby, I had to make a couple of improvements to my query to form a clearer plan, but eventually the conclusion is that yes, it seems to call the subquery only when necessary, which can be seen from both the plan's row counts and from overall query performance.

Answer (score 0):

> The CASE expression evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops
> with the first condition whose condition is satisfied

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

so it would run  the select only if the first condition is false

That is not true for all possibilities, if you use an aggregation it will be processed first, which is mentioned in the link abouve.

> Aggregate expressions that appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE expression are evaluated first,

we had here threads where people compared correlated subqueries against inner joins and couldn't find any difference in speed.

Comment: Not always true (e.g. [aggregates](https://dbfiddle.uk/FFjlX0My)).

Comment: this isn't a aggregation it is a correlated subquery

Comment: Ok. What you're saying in your answer _still_ isn't true all the time, and you should qualify that there are exceptions. The documentation even goes on to say, "In some situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE expression receives the results of the expression as its input. Errors in evaluating these expressions are possible."

Comment: (Just nudging you to provide a little clarity in your answer, since quoting _only_ that sentence is misleading, and is probably the kind of thing that causes a lot of people believe that `CASE` _always_ short circuits.)

Comment: i added the point about aggregation functions. to make it clearer, but as microsoft doesn't mention any other situations i still think that correlated subqueries run row by row

Comment: @nbk I know that CASE stops evaluation on the first match, but it is not clear if the data is already collected by the time of CASE evaluation. Your referenced documentation says about "some" case and gives aggregate expressions as an example of exception. From the way it is written, it is not clear if there are other cases, which exactly, and how many.

Comment: Conditions will be processed sequentially yes, but does not prove that it ll execute subquery conditionally.